# Display a post based on its metabox selection

Tags: php, functions, filters, metabox, array

I created a client portal where a client can view their projects. I have two user accounts "Clients" and "Administrator. Both clients and administrator are redirected to the frontend of the site to a dashboard that displays recent projects once they sign in.

- When clients signs in they will see their projects.
- When an administrator signs in they will see all projects for every
  client.

What I am trying to achieve is when an "Administrator" signs in they will only see pending projects in the Dashboard instead of all project status. Clients will need to stay the same by displaying all project status in the dashboard.

The project status can be selected in the backend from a drop down metabox.

**This is my array for project status**

```
 array(
            'name'    => __( 'Project Status', 'projects' ),
            'desc'    => __( '', 'projects' ),
            'id'      => $prefix . 'project_select',
            'type'    => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                'Select a Status'   => __( 'Select a Status', 'projects' ),
                'Draft'                 => __( 'Draft', 'projects' ),
                'Open'              => __( 'Open', 'projects' ),
                'Pending'           => __( 'Pending', 'projects' ),
                'Closed'            => __( 'Closed', 'projects' ),
                'Completed'         => __( 'Completed', 'projects' ),
            ),
        ),
```

**This is the code I am using to display all projects on the dashboard.**

```
 <?php 
  function filter_posts_by_author( $query ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
            global $current_user; 
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
        }
    }
    else {
        wp_die('Sorry, you do not have access to this page. Please <a href="/#/">sign in</a> to view this page.');
    }
}
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_by_author' );
 ?>

 <?php 
        global $post; 
        $projects = new WP_Query( array( 
           'post_type'          => array( 'projects'),
           'posts_per_page'     => 5,
           'orderby'            => 'ASC',
           'paged'          => $paged,
      )); 
 ?>
  <?php if ( $projects->have_posts() ) : while ( $projects->have_posts() ) :       $projects->the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"class="postTable">
        <ul>
              <li class="rowLarge">
              <h3>Project Name</h3>
              <p><?php the_title( '' ); ?></p>
              </li>
              <li class="rowSmall">
              <h3>Date Added</h3>
              <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'clientType', true); ?> <?php the_time(' F jS, Y') ?></p>
              </li>
              <li class="rowSmall">
              <h3>Project Type</h3>
              <p><?php $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tagPro', '', ', ', '' ) ; echo strip_tags($terms_as_text);?></p>
              </li>
              <li class="rowSmall">
              <h3>Project Status</h3>
              <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_project_select', true); ?></p>
              </li>
              <li class="rowLarge options">
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="icon icon-eye"><p>View</p></a>
              <?php $feLink = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_image', true) ; if (!empty($feLink)) { ?>
              <a href="<?php if (!strstr($feLink, "http://") ) {echo "http://";} echo $feLink; ?>" class="icon icon-upload" target="_blank"><p>Download</p></a><?php } ?>            
              <?php if ( comments_open() ) : comments_popup_link( ' 0', ' 1', ' %', 'comments-link icon icon-bubble', 'Off'); endif; ?>
              <?php edit_post_link('', '', ''); ?>
              </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
  <?php global $user_ID; if( $user_ID ) : ?><?php if( current_user_can('level_10') ) : ?>
  <p class="clientName"><strong>Client |</strong> <?php the_author(); ?></p>                    
  <?php else: endif; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
  </article>
  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
  <h5>No Projects have been posted </h5>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? Seems like you just need meta query parameters in your query for admins.

Comment: When an administrator signs in I would like to only display "pending" projects instead of all project status (completed, draft etc). But when a client signs in I what them to be able to view all project status. What you are stating seems to be exactly what I need, I just can't figure out how to achieve it. @Milo